# looping sounds in windows phone 7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, soundeffect

I am trying to get a sound to loop when a button is pressed, and then stop the sound when the same button is pressed again. I have multiple sounds that are playing at the same time (all are looping), all the sounds should be able to start and stop in any order.

My Issue?

If you press one button then the sound loops fine and it will stop when the button is pressed again, however if you press one button (so one sound is looping) and then press another (to try and play both sounds at the same time) then the first sound is stopped, and I cant for the life of me figure out why?

My code:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {


        SoundEffect sound3;
        int x = 0;

        StreamResourceInfo SoundFileInfo = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri("tracks/drum (human).wav", UriKind.Relative));

        sound3 = SoundEffect.FromStream(SoundFileInfo.Stream);

        SoundEffectInstance sound3instance = sound3.CreateInstance();


        if (button3.Content.Equals("Sound 3"))
        {
            sound3instance.IsLooped = true;
            sound3instance.Play();
            button3.Content = "Playing";
        }
        else
        {
            sound3instance.Pause();
            button3.Content = "Sound 3";
        }

    }

    private void button4_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        SoundEffect sound4;

        StreamResourceInfo SoundFileInfo2 = App.GetResourceStream(new Uri("Cow Moo 1.wav", UriKind.Relative));

        sound4 = SoundEffect.FromStream(SoundFileInfo2.Stream);

        SoundEffectInstance sound4instance = sound4.CreateInstance();


        if (button4.Content.Equals("Sound 4"))
        {
            sound4instance.IsLooped = true;
            sound4instance.Play();
            button4.Content = "PLaying";
        }
        else
        {
            sound4instance.Pause();
            button4.Content = "Sound 4";
        }
    }
```

Many Thanks,

Jake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

are the sound3instance and the sound4instance stored outside the methods?

Comment: But I can get the sounds loop over each other fine but only if I remove the if that checks for the button content (too check if the sound should play or stop)?

Comment: no they are created in the method and only then... I shall try moving that now

Comment: thank you it works now!!! (now I look at it a stupid mistake but I would never have spotted it)